# How to convert local git repository back to vs2015 project files?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, repository

I foolishly clicked 'Publish' bottom right hand corner of vs2015 whilst my project was open, now my project file have been converted into what appears to be a git local repository, how do I get my project files back?

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Try checking out the HEAD?

Answer (score 0):

Usually checking `git status` tells you what you need to do, for it tells you every file that has changed. So, if your files where deleted, all you have to do is

```
git checkout -- .
```

This will revert all uncommitted changes. If, however, the changes where committed, you can do

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

Please note that the second line of code I presented will send you back one commit prior to the one you're in (HEAD), with no (trivial) way of undoing.

Comment: I tried both but no sign of files returning, maybe something is corrupted, but its not showing the missing project(GUI_1_)in vs, but it's there in the folder(see pic) as a .db file.

Comment: Can you post the result of git status?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but I've added another pic to the OP.  That entry you can see at 07:14AM is the time I clicked the publish button and the trouble started.

Comment: I meant to say I need you to post the result of the command `git status`, executed in the project directory. Follow this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/gitquickstart?tabs=visual-studio and post the result of the Changes option.

Comment: 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: I have a feeling my project has vanished into the ether, what an utter awful feature to a) not warn it was going to convert my project b) no easy way to step back

Comment: Did you try to follow the guide I posted?

Comment: Right click the only repo available in 'Local Git Repositories' window, select 'open command prompt', run 'git status' ?

Comment: Hm... that's not what I meant. Try clicking the Home icon and choose Changes. See if anything pops out.